# Is there a Java backed API equivalent to react-jsonschema-form?

Tags: react-jsonschema-forms

Given a JSONSchema and a UISchema, is there an equivalent backend library that does all of these form validations?

We currently use `Json-schema` library in Java for backend. We're having issues using this JSON validator for Dynamic Dropdown type schema forms (where 1 drop down selection will dynamically introduce other dropdown selections).

We're unable to get the same validation errors as the one that is done by react-jsonschema-forms.